# What's the best way search a Ruby Hash for key-value pairs matching a value and then changing that value?

Tags: ruby

Simply stated my breakdown is this: 
1. Find Hash that contains a value of "option"
2. Prompt user to what value of "option" should be
3. Change "option" into value user wanted (11 or 1)

I'm building a Blackjack game to better understand Ruby, and am trying to have users able to switch out values from a "hand."  I store the deck as a Hash containing the deck and then scoring value like this :D8 => 8 where it's an eight of Diamonds worth eight points. Aces, because they can be either 1 or 11 get stored like this: :SA => "option."

I would like to be able to prompt the user to for a value or This is currently part of the code:

```
def checkAce
    if @player_hand.has_value?("option")

        puts "What do you want your aces to be worth? 11 or 1"

        ace_value = gets.chomp
        aces = @player_hand.find {|k, v| @player_hand[k] == "option"}

        if ace_value == "1" || ace_value == "11"
            aces.each { |k, v| aces[k] = ace_value }
        else 
            checkAce
        end 

        # merge back into hand 
        @player_hand.merge!(aces)

    else
        puts "No aces, so on to the main event." 
    end 
end
```

But this code doesn't work: first, the ace_value gives me a typeerror saying that symbol cannot be coerced into integer. And second, the @player_hand.merge!(aces) doesn't find a method.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very necessary to use [merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21). Just iterate the hash to change corresponding value.

```
def check_ace
  if @player_hand.has_value?("option")
    # get your input ace_value
    # ...
    if ["1", "11"].include?(ace_value)
      @player_hand.each_key { |k| @player_hand[k] = ace_value if @player_hand[k] == "option" }
    else
      check_ace
    end
  else
    puts "No aces, so on to the main event."  
  end
end
```

Comment: I ended up going with this because it was very easy to follow and it worked. I was unaware also about the if syntax! Thanks again!

Comment: @user3162553 The one line mode `if` statement is just a convenient code style, you can read more Ruby code style best practise: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 1):

The error with your code lies here:

```
aces = @player_hand.find {|k, v| @player_hand[k] == "option"}
```

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), find returns the first matching value, not every matching value. What you probably want is [`#find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all).

For example:

```
hand = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 'option', d: 'option' }
hand.find { |_, v| v == 'option' } # => [:c, "option"]
hand.find_all { |_, v| v == 'option' } # => [[:c, "option"], [:d, "option"]]
```

You'll also notice that what's returned is not a hash, but an array. You can use [`Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) to get back a hash.

For example:

```
Hash[[:c, "option"], [:d, "option"]] # => {[:c, "option"]=>[:d, "option"]}
```

So putting that together, you can extract the relevant parts of the hash with the following:

```
hand = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 'option', d: 'option' }
aces = Hash[hand.find_all { |_, v| v == 'option' }]
```

The rest of your code works as expected:

```
ace_value = 4
aces.each { |k, v| aces[k] = ace_value }
hand.merge!(aces) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>4, :d=>4}
```

I don't really know the "best" way to change the value in a hash that matches a value, but the following is probably less work:

```
hand = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 'option', d: 'option' }
option_value = 'option'
ace_value = 4
hand.each do |k, v|
  if v == option_value
    hand[k] = ace_value
  end 
end # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>4, :d=>4}
```

which you can shorten to

```
hand.each { |k, v| hand[k] = ace_value if v == option_value }
```

if you feel like it.

Comment: This is really helpful - thank you very much for the detailed explanation.  I missed the find_all in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

So, mapping through a hash is a bit clunky in ruby. Here's the basic idea though:

```
data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

data = data.map do |k, v|
  if k == :b
    [k, 4]
  else
    [k, v]
  end
end.to_h

p(data)                         #=> {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>3}
```

If someone knows an easier/cleaner way, I would be interested in seeing it as well.

EDIT: `coderz` has a better answer, since in this case, you only need to change a few values, not map the entire hash.